# Sorting a google sheet where some columns are form driven

Tags: sorting

I have two sheets.

Sheet A is the sheet which collects data submitted by a form.

Sheet B is an assignment sheet.  This sheet uses =query to import Column A, B, C, D, E from Sheet A.  Column F, G, H are user inputted columns.

Is there a way to sort the data from Newest date  to Oldest Column A and keep Column F, G, H with the row it was originally inputted on.

Right now I am running a script for Sheet A which sorts Column A upon form submit.  This only sorts Column A-E on Sheet B and I need it to Sort A-H on Sheet B

Any ideas?

Comment: What script are you running? could that perhaps be changed to do the other sheets too?

Comment: I don't know that appengine has "sheet"